# How is dc restorer circuit used for PWM demodulation/detection?

Tags: dc, pwm, demodulation, high-pass-filter, diode-clamp

In the Microelectronics Circuits textbook by Sedra & Smith, it is said that:

> As an application, consider a pulse signal being transmitted through a capacitively coupled or ac-coupled system. The capactive coupling will cause the pulse train to lose whatever dc component it originally had. Feeding the resulting pulse waveform to a clamping circuit provides it with a well-determined dc component, a process known as dc restoration. This is why the circuit is also called a dc restorer.
>
> Restoring dc is useful because the dc component or average value of a pulse waveform is an effective measure of its duty cycle. The duty cycle of a pulse waveform can be modulated (in a process called pulsewidth modulation) and made to carry information. In such a system, detection or demodulation could be achieved simply by feeding the received pulse waveform to a dc restorer and then using a simple RC low pass filter to separate the average of the output waveform from the superimposed pulses.

*From: Microelectronic Circuits by Adel S. Sedra & Kenneth C. Smith "The Clamped Capacitor or DC Restorer" - section 4.6.2 in 6th Edition, or section 3.6.2 in 5th Edition*

Now I thought the dc restorer circuit is supposed to perform voltage level shift. How does it also demodulate a PWM signal?

The process mentions the pulse signal going through an ac-coupled system and then feeding it to dc restorer. Doesn't this just change the signal from DC to AC then DC? How is the width translated to magnitude? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider an AC coupled PWM signal. Its peak-peak amplitude is constant at (let's say) 5V, regardless of the duty cycle. And its mean value is ... 0 ... regardless of the duty cycle.

Now use a DC restorer to define the DC level of its negative peaks at 0V. The positive peaks are now 5V.

All you need to do is low pass filter it, and the output value between 0 and 5V represents the duty cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand the latter part now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand the latter part now. In the beginning, It says that: "As an application, consider a pulse signal being transmitted through a capacitively coupled or ac-coupled system. The capactive coupling will cause the pulse train to lose whatever dc component it originally had. " So the ac coupling is supposed to remove the original dc component. Is this assuming that the pulse signal before going through ac coupling has a dc bias of sorts? (say 2V to 7V with peak-peak amplitude = 5V). If not, can we just use DC restorer on the original pulse signal?

Comment: Not sure I understand this comment. AC coupling assumes nothing about the DC level on the input : if there is a DC bias, it removes it. If you're asking if you can use a DC restorer on a DC coupled signal : no you can't. (However you can always AC couple it into your DC restorer. That gives you your choice of DC level, not the original signal's.)

Comment: My mistake. I meant to say feeding the original pulse wave that didn't go through AC coupling directly to a LPF. The book is saying that the process: original pulse wave -> AC coupling -> DC restorer -> LPF is PWM signal demodulation. Wouldn't it be simpler if we just do original pulse wave -> LPF to retrieve the demodulated signal? I'm curious whether or not losing the original DC component makes a difference in real-world application.

Comment: Ah OK - yes if you have the original DC level and you know where 0% and 100% are on it, yes all you need is an LPF. But that means you haven't transmitted PWM though the sort of system the book is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

By using a negative clamp and a LPF of any order to give desired BW yet attenuate PWM ripple, the result is a DC +AC signal proportional toward the PWM duty cycle.